# Speed difference between spark.read.parquet and spark.read.format.load

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to understand what is causing the huge difference in reading speed. I have a dataframe with 30 million rows and 38 columns.

```py
final_df=spark.read.parquet("/dbfs/FileStore/path/to/file.parquet")
```

This takes 14 minutes to read the file.

While

```py
final_df = spark.read.format("parquet").load("/dbfs/FileStore/path/to/file.parquet")
```

Takes only 2 seconds to read the file.

Comment: Ideally both of them should take less than 5 seconds as just writing spark.read does not start reading file on spark unless later an action is called on that df

Comment: That is what I was also thinking. But I've repeated this twice and same thing happened both times. It has to be loading to memory in the first case.

Comment: you should test them in two different sessions, not in the same session.

Comment: Try reading other way around "spark.read.format" first to check if the first run is actually takes less time then the second one.

Comment: The second takes only takes about 2 seconds because you have already executed the first one. If you change the order of the execution  I guess the first one will take only 2 seconds. However 14 Minutes is more than I would expected. You might have too many small files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`spark.read.parquet(filename)` and `spark.read.format("parquet").load(filename)` do exactly the same thing.

We can see this in the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/5103e00c4ce5fcc4264ca9c4df12295d42557af6/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.scala#L550-L563) (taking Spark 3.3.2, latest version at the time of this post).

```scala
  /**
   * Loads a Parquet file, returning the result as a `DataFrame`.
   *
   * Parquet-specific option(s) for reading Parquet files can be found in
   * <a href=
   *   "https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#data-source-option">
   *   Data Source Option</a> in the version you use.
   *
   * @since 1.4.0
   */
  @scala.annotation.varargs
  def parquet(paths: String*): DataFrame = {
    format("parquet").load(paths: _*)
  }
```

We see that calling `spark.read.parquet(filename)` is actually a kind of "alias" for `spark.read.format("parquet").load(filename)`.

#### Conclusion

Those 2 methods of reading in files are exactly the same. Also, reading in a file with these methods is a lazy transformation, not an action. Only 2 seconds to read in a dataset of 30 million rows and 38 columns is extremely quick, probably too quick (depending on your hardware).

So in your case, one of the following might have happened:

- Maybe you called an action after the "slow" one, triggering an actual read and did not do that for the "quick" one. The "quick" one did not actually read in the file.
- Maybe after the first read, your dataset was cached somehow. This could remove the need of reading in the file again.
- ...or something else :)